# Is it possible to run a vbscript from within a zipfile that is an attachment in outlook and extract the files?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

'Lets say i have a file test.zip and inside this file is test.vbs and some other files.
'I have attached this zipfile as an attachment and sent it.
'Now in MS Outlook i double click on the zipfile to open it, what i would like now is to 'be able to run this test.vbs file directly from the opened window which points to  - 
'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook
'\test.zip and copy the files to a specified folder.

```
strZIPname = "test.zip"
strFileDest = "c:\test\"

Function UnPack(strZIPdest, strZIPname)
  Dim intOptions, objShell, objSource, objTarget

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZIPname)
  Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(strZIPdest)

 intOptions = 16
 If objFSO.FolderExists(strZIPdest) Then
   objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("calendar.jpg"), intOptions 'error occurs here
   'objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("facebook.jpg"), intOptions
   'objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("linkedin.jpg"), intOptions
   'objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("main_logo.png"), intOptions
   'objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("twitter.jpg"), intOptions
 Else
   MsgBox "Cannot complete unzip for " & strZIPname & ". The destination directory (" & strZIPdest & ") could not be located.", 0, "Invalid"
 End If
  Set objFSO = Nothing
  Set objShell = Nothing
  Set objSource = Nothing
  Set objTarget = Nothing
End Function
```

'this code works only if the zip file exists on the desktop otherwise i get an error - 
'object required: 'objsource'

Comment: 'okay here is my revised code, maybe still a bit messy but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You must save VBS file first -- anywhere on your hard drive, and ONLY after that you will be able to run it.

Comment: I got it working. I will post the code once i have fixed it up. thanks

Comment: I am sorry, you was able to run VBS file from inside of ZIP archive?!

Comment: Yes but i had to provide part of the path for where the opened zip is stored. I will post my script once i have made it look better because at the moment looks very messy. -thanks

Answer (score 0):

'This now works. I had to use expandenviroment to get userprofile and then add the rest of 'the path so that the vbscript will find the path of the zip file. Also at the end delete 'the zipfile from the folder otherwise windows creates copies of the same zipfile.
If anyone has a better way of doing this please post your code thanks.

```
Dim objFSO, objWsh
Set objWsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
userprofilePath = objWsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
strPath = userprofilePath & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook\"
'wscript.echo strpath
appDataPath = objWsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
pathToCopyTo = appDataPath & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
strFileDest = pathToCopyTo
'wscript.echo strfiledest
strZIPname1 = "unzip6.zip"
strZIPname2 = "unzip6 (2).zip"
strZIPname3 = "unzip6 (3).zip"

Call Search (strPath)
WScript.Echo"Done."
Set objWsh = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing

Sub Search(str)
    Dim objFolder, objSubFolder, objFile, intOptions, objShell, objSource, objTarget
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(str)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'If objFile.DateLastModified < (Now() - 30) Then
            if objfile.name = strZIPname1 or objfile.name = strZIPname2 or objfile.name = strZIPname3 then
                'wscript.echo "File found at this path: " & str&"\"&objfile.name
                'Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(str&"\"&objfile.name)
                Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(strFileDest)
                intOptions = 16
                If objFSO.FolderExists(strFileDest) Then
                objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("calendar.jpg"), intOptions
                objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("facebook.jpg"), intOptions
                objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("linkedin.jpg"), intOptions
                objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("main_logo.png"), intOptions
                objTarget.CopyHere objSource.Items.item("twitter.jpg"), intOptions
                Else
                MsgBox "Cannot complete unzip for " & strZIPname & ". The destination directory (" & strZIPdest & ") could not be located.", 0, "Invalid"
                End If
            objFile.Delete(True)
        End If
    Next
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Search(objSubFolder.Path)
    Next
Set objFolder = Nothing
'Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objSource = Nothing
Set objTarget = Nothing
End Sub
```